# Geometry Prove( I need many methods)

Tags: geometry

[image: The picture of this question]

$ABCD$ is a square, and $p$ is a dot in the square. if $AP=1, BP=2, CP=3$. Find the area of $ABCD$.

Comment: What have you tried? What methods do you have?

Comment: I tried to use area to prove this question.

Comment: The root $5 - 2\sqrt 2$ is rejected not just because it carries a negative sign. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Rotate the square $90^ \circ $ counter-clockwise about $B$.

> $P$ goes to $P'$, $ \angle P'BP = 90^ \circ, BP=BP' = 2$ so $ BP = 2\sqrt{2}$ and $ \angle P'PB = 45^\circ$.
>  $PAP'$ has side lengths $1 - 3 - 2 \sqrt{2}$, which is a right triangle with $ \angle APP' = 90^\circ$.
>  So $ \angle APB = \angle APP' + \angle PP'B = 135^\circ$.

Thus $AB^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 - 2 \times 2 \angle APP' = 5 + 2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: How did you know that ∠P'AP and ∠P'BP are right angle?

Comment: 1) $BP$ rotated by $90^\circ$ gives us $BP'$, so $\angle PBP' = 90^\circ$. 2) $\angle APP' = 90^\circ$  because of the side lengths of $APP'$.

Comment: Thank you, you won't believe this question is for a 13-year-old kid.

Comment: In that case, let me see if there is another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle PBA =\phi$. Using cosine law, $$l^2+4-4l\cos\phi=1\tag 1$$
$$l^2+4-4l\sin\phi= 9\tag 2$$

$$\implies \cos\phi={l^2+3\over 4l}$$
$$\implies \sin\phi=\pm{\sqrt{16l^2-l^4-9-6l^2}\over 4l}=\pm{\sqrt{16-(l^2-5)^2}\over 4l}\tag 3$$

From $(2), (3)$ we have

$$l^2-5\pm\sqrt{16-(l^2-5)^2}=0$$ $$\implies (l^2-5)^2=16-(l^2-5)^2 \implies (l^2-5)^2=8$$
$$\implies l^2=5\pm 2\sqrt 2$$

Comment: You also need "P is within the square" to reject the negative value.

Comment: Thank you, you won't believe this question is for a 13-year-old kid.

Comment: @CalvinLin yeah, but the answer would be the same in the end, no?

Comment: As in, right now, you have 2 possible answers for the area of the square. Your solution currently implies that both answers are possible.

Comment: Would the issue of the angle internally dividing the angle of the square not be sorted when both sides are squared after the line “From $(2), ~(3)$ we have...? Although by intuition it does indeed seem there should be only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is a variation of @Certainlynotadog   ‘s

We already have $\cos\phi={l^2+3\over 4l}$

Similarly we can have $\sin \phi={l^2-5\over 4l}$

Then, $({l^2+3\over 4l})^2 + ({l^2-5\over 4l})^2 = 1$.

Since the value of $l^2$ is our target, we can let $x = l^2$

Then, after simplification, we have $x^2 – 10x + 17 = 0$

Therefore, $l^2 = x = 5\pm 2\sqrt 2$

The negative value has to be rejected because P is either outside the square or somewhere very near to the corner D so that the other given conditions cannot be achieved.

[image]

Comment: Why is $(\frac {l^2+3}{4l})^2+(\frac {l^2-5}{4l})^2=1$

Comment: Oh, nothing. I think I know why.

Comment: How did you get the equation "$sin\phi=\frac{l^2-5}{4l}$" ?

Comment: @ASTUDENT Apply cosine law to $\triangle PBC$, $ \dfrac {l^2 + 2^2 – 3^2}{2(l)(2)} = \cos (90 - \phi) = \sin \phi$.